# Scala Play Json JSResultException Validation Error

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying to pass this json string to my other method but SOMETIMES I get this error,

> play.api.libs.json.JsResultException:
>   JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))

I find it strange that this occurs randomly, sometimes I don't get the exception and sometimes I do. Any ideas?

Here is what my json looks like

```
val string = {
  "first_name" : {
    "type" : "String",
    "value" : "John"
  },
  "id" : {
    "type" : "String",
    "value" : "123456789"
  },
  "last_name" : {
    "type" : "String",
    "value" : "Smith"
  }
}
```

I read it like

```
(string \ "first_name").as[String]
```

Comment: What result do you get when you don't get an exception? Because the value of `first_name` field apparently is not just a string value.

Comment: And `string` is not Json.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(string \ "first_name")` gives `JsValue` not `JsString` so `as[String]` does not work.

But if you need `first name value` you can do

```
val firstName = ((json \ "first_name") \ "value").as[String]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another option to consider for type safety while reading and writing Json with play Json API. Below I am showing using your json as example reading part and writing is analogous.

1. Represent data as case classes.

   `case Person(id:Map[String,String], firstName:Map[String,String], lastName:[String,String]`
2. Write implicit read/write for your case classes.

   `implicit val PersonReads: Reads[Person]`
3. Employ plays combinator read API's. Import the implicit where u read the json and you get back the Person object. Below is the illustration.

   `val personObj = Json.fromJson[Person](json)`

Please have a look here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

Answer (score -3):

First of all you can't traverse a **String** object, so your input must be converted to **JsValue** to be able to traverse it:

```
 val json = Json.parse(string)
```

then the **first_name**   attribut is of **JsValue** type and not a **String** so if you try to extract the **first_name** value like you do you will get always a **JsResultException**.

I can only explain the random appearance of **JsResultException** by a radom change in your **first_name** field json structure. make sur your sting input to traverse has always a fixed **first_name** filed structure.